# Положительно - частица?

Tags: грамматика

Сегодня, решая олимпиаду  по русскому языку, наткнулся на вопрос.

Какие знаки препинания могут быть при частице положительно? Само собой разумеется,

запятая

точка

ни один из вариантов

тире

двоеточие

все варианты

Вопрос. Слово положительно может быть частицей? В Викисловаре написано: в знач. усилительной частицы решительно, совсем ◆ Да, нам положительно некуда так торопиться. Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк, «Хлеб», 1895 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы) ◆ Положительно всю дорогу пешком шёл, но явился в срок. Л. Н. Толстой, «Анна Каренина», 1878 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы) ◆ Положительно ничто не могло ускользнуть от не в меру проницательных глаз этой Дуняшки… М. А. Шолохов, «Тихий Дон», 1928—1940 г.

Но в официальных словарях  при этом значении дается только помет. разг.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть ещё одно надёжное издание (не понимаю, почему М_Г убрал свой ответ с Грамоты.ру) -

**[Малый академический словарь русского языка](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-57561.htm)**

> ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО
>
> *нареч.*
>
> **1.**
>
> *Нареч*. к *положительный* ([в 1, 2, 4 и 6 знач.](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-57563.htm)).
>
> *Отнестись положительно к предложению. Вопрос решен положительно.*
>
> □
>
> *Мне положительно известно, что дядя, по приказанию Фомы, принужден был сбрить свои прекрасные, темно-русые бакенбарды.* Достоевский, Село
>   Степанчиково.
>
> **2.**
>
> В полном смысле слова.
>
> *Но так называемая девичья положительно могла назваться убежищем скорби.* Салтыков-Щедрин, Пошехонская старина.
>
> *Федот был положительно красноречив, почти вдохновенен, когда рассказывал Миньоне о своих страданиях.* Скиталец, Миньона.
>
> ||
>
> *в знач. усилительной частицы*. Решительно, совсем.
>
> *{Рюмин:} Меня положительно возмущает ее деспотизм.* М. Горький, Дачники.
>
> *Нет, нет, Григорий положительно стал не тот!* Шолохов, Тихий Дон.
>
> ||
>
> *в знач. вводн. сл.* Конечно, как видно по всему.
>
> *— Нет, положительно, эта девчонка пойдет далеко.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Горное гнездо.
>
> *Она поставила на стол две рюмки — одну для него, другую для себя: положительно, с Таней творилось сегодня что-то из ряда вон выходящее.*
>   Березко, Необыкновенные москвичи.

Вывод. При частице *положительно* не может быть никаких знаков, если только слово случайно не совпало с концом предложения (точка) или с "чужой" запятой.

А тире (оно же в функции двоеточия), пожалуй, возможно, если словом "положительно" предложение дробится на части:

*Ни то, ни сё, ни пятое, ни десятое, ни в огороде бузина, ни в Киеве дядька - положительно ничто не могло ускользнуть от не в меру проницательных глаз этой Дуняшки* (Нешолохов).

---

Постскриптум.

Не могу поступиться принципами (с) - про двоеточие недорассказано, но так как я в теории ни бум-бум, не могу определить частица ли *положительно* в сочиненном:

*Положительно: ни то, ни сё, ни пятое, ни десятое, ни в огороде бузина, ни в Киеве дядька - ничто не могло ускользнуть от не в меру проницательных глаз этой Дуняшки.*

> [§ 161.](http://kudyaplik.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_12.html) Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно
>   или несколько предложений, не соединённых с первым посредством союзов
>   и заключающих в себе:
>
> а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чём говорится в первом
>   предложении, например:
>
> *Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана* (Пушкин).

Будем думать, что частица у нас... эээ... предложение? Но если смыслово оно равно слову *решительно*, то это наречие.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

> **РЕШИТЕЛЬНО. I. *нареч.* 1.** к Решительный. *Действовать р. Р. стоять на своём. Р. отказать в чём-л. Она р. сказала, что не поедет.*
>   **2.** Совсем, совершенно. *Р. ничего не понял. Мне р. всё равно: идти в театр или на танцы. В марте р. потеплело.* **II. *частица*.**
>   Выражает усиление, полноту охвата чего-л.; без исключения. *Он нужен
>   р. всем. Ему нравится в ней р. всё. Всем р. говорил "ты". Он бывал
>   здесь р. каждый день.* **III.*вводн. сл.***  Разумеется, без сомнения.
>   *И даже отвернулась от собеседника; р., он ей надоел. Тебе, р., улыбнулось счастье.*

Comment: @ Galina Avanesova, видимо, недостатки интернет- издания. Я смотрел в том же словаре на академике, там ничего не говорилось про частицу.

Comment: Проверила я этого академика - https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype= - и не увидела ссылки на Малый академический словарь русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

В нескольких разных книгах слово **положительно** относят к частицам. Упомяну только наиболее известных авторов: Лопатин, Розенталь, Шведова. Для примера, приведу цитату из "Русской грамматики" Шведовой:

> К простым частицам относятся все первообразные частицы (см. выше), а
>   также частицы, в разной степени обнаруживающие живые связи с союзами,
>   местоименными словами, наречиями, глаголами или предлогами. Кроме
>   первообразных частиц, к простым частицам относятся: *а, благо, более,
>   больше, буквально, бывает, бывало, было, будто, ведь, во (прост.),
>   вовсе, вон, вот, вроде, всё, всего, где,  гляди, да (не в составе
>   формы повелит, накл.), давай(те), даже, дай(те), действительно,
>   единственно, если, еще, знай, и, или, именно, как, какое, куда, ладно,
>   ли, лучше, никак (прост., вопросит.), ничего, нечего, но, однако, 
>   окончательно, оно, поди (прост.), **положительно**, просто, прямо,
>   пусть, пускай, разве, решительно, ровно, самое, себе, скорее, словно,
>   совершенно, спасибо (в знач. 'хорошо'), так, там, тебе, тоже, только,
>   точно, хоть, чего, чисто (прост.),  что, чтоб, чтобы, эк, это.*

Далеко не все перечисленные выше слова упомянуты в словаре Кузнецова как частицы.